# Store a cache COPY of table locally SQL Server

Tags: c#, .net, c++, sql-server-2008, caching

- Is it possible to store a cache copy of the table data locally to avoid transfer (data does not change, This I assure it!) in `SQL Server`. So `C++, C#`  can know the data stored by SQL  in cache and then read the data in cache and compute some things with the table?
- Is it possible this kind of communication between `SQL Server and C++ or C#` via cache memory copy of table data?

  - If this is possible, What would be the steps?

Comment: have you looked at DataSets? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataset%28v=vs.71%29.aspx

Comment: mmm, Not sure if this is possible, but, Can all this be inside the DBMS (SQL Server)?, Also if using DataSets, after the table scan, is it possible to keep all calculus in memory or in cache?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ADO.You need to use ADO.NET (Disconnected) DataSets:

1) Create a Dataset

```
DataSet dsCustomers = new DataSet();
```

2) Create a DataAdapter, specifying what data to get

```
SqlDataAdapter daCustomers = new SqlDataAdapter(
    "select CustomerID, CompanyName from Customers", conn);
```

3) Fill the Dataset

```
daCustomers.Fill(dsCustomers, "Customers");
```

After which you can Query your Dataset.

Comment: Is it possible, that supossing the SQL table is already in memory, access it only reading memory?, this to avoid reading the table again,just the memory

Comment: This reads the table into memory.  You are only getting it once.

Comment: SQL Server does'nt allow you to directly access Tables (in memory or disk). You need to go through the SQL Driver. Data Sets are In memory structures so the only way is to get all your SQL Data once into these memory structures, and query them hence forth (assuming your table data does'nt change as you mentioned).

Comment: @AKhil: You say SQL Server does not allow direct access, so is there a way to know the memory address or something OR is it mandatory to do the process you mention?

Comment: @cMinor, even if SQL Server Stores table Data in Memory, its not advisable for your application to parse the memory format used, etc. I see the Dataset approach as the closest. Moreover, Datasets are very fast as they are in-memory. You only need to get Data the First time, after which you have data in-memory.

Comment: @Akhil: I was asking because I would like avoiding reading a huge table in C++ or C# if I already have it in memory, so this is the only way through right?

Comment: yes, i would say. I understand your concern, but its not at all advisable to get Data from SQL Server or any other application in an unsafe way(direct memory access to internal storage)!!

Comment: Only for curiosity, How would be the unsafe way of direct memory access?

Comment: @cMinor:  Don't. Do. That.  Poking into another processes memory space is Bad.